# "Is time to be happy" Or "It is time to be happy"

Tags: grammar

I want to say: "Es momento de ser feliz". How can say that?

Is time to be happy.

Or

It is time to be happy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about comparisons of grammar structures used in English and a foreign language.

Comment: I have no problem with this question as-is and I hope that it stays open.

Answer (score 2):

You must use *It is*, because [an English sentence must have a subject](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/subject.htm).  You can't just have a verb without a subject - something has to be performing the verb.

Sometimes it's not obvious what the subject is.  For example, here, what does "it" refer to?  What is time to be happy?  The answer to that is that [we often use *it* as the subject when it's not clear what the subject is, which we call the *dummy it*.](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/minor/dummy.htm)

Comment: I've upvoted your answer, but I'd like to add that the preposition could be used here: _It's time to be happy._ (That's probably how I'd say it in most contexts.) Also, you could eliminate the _It is_ altogether. The result would be a fragment perhaps unsuitable for formal writing, but perfectly acceptable in conversation: _Finally, the weekend is here. Time to be happy._

Comment: @J.R. - Good points.  You can leave out "it is", but the noteworthy thing is that then we don't even have a verb in the subject.  If we're going to have a verb, we have to have a subject doing the verb (unless we're doing "diary drop"...but that's another topic!)

Comment: Yes, an English sentence must have a subject.  But verbs don't always represent actions (*is* does not here), and the subject does not always perform that action (*it* does not here).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "verbs don't represent actions" or what the relevance of that is, since I didn't use that term, unless you're pointing out that *is* here represents a state of being, but "it" is certainly being something.

Comment: @stangdon Sorry, I'll rephrase that.  The subject is not performing anything because there is no action expressed by the verb to perform.  English has a grammatical requirement for a subject, but it is not true that "something has to be performing the verb".  When we say "It's raining", *it* is not performing *is raining*.  *It* and *is* are just there for grammatical reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct sentence:

> It is time to be happy.

The word "It" is a pronoun that refers to a noun or pronoun in the sentence or in another sentence that comes before your sentence. This word that the pronoun "It" stands for is called an "antecedent." In your sentence with the linking verb "is"; the verb "is" links "It" to its antecedent: *time*. *It* = *time*.

This is how linking verbs work. The word that comes after the linking verb is either a noun that "identifies or explains" the subject, or it is an adjective to "describe" the subject. Your sentence is using a noun, "time." When no antecedent can be found in the sentence or any sentence before the sentence, then is **it** "indefinite" and sometimes referred to as a *dummy **it***, as someone else mentioned.

Here's another sentence with an antecedent for **it** that's found in a previous sentence: I like *milk*. *It* tastes so wholesome. The antecedent for "It" is milk. PROOF: Milk tastes so wholesome.

I took the *magazine* and put *it* in the garbage because I was done reading *it*. [No linking verbs to show you more about "it" being a pronoun with the antecedent "magazine."]

https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/pro_antagree.htm

Linking verbs, sometimes called state-of-being verbs express no action; instead they link words in a sentence. If the subject is described by the *word* coming after the linking verb, then it's called a *predicate adjective*.

e.g.

The *car* is *red*. [*red* is an adjective describing the color of the *car*, and it's a predicate adjective.]

The other one, the predicate nominative is a noun or pronoun that doesn't describe but identifies or explains the subject.

e.g.

My vehicle is a car. [*car* "identifies" WHAT the subject is; it's a *vehicle*, which can be many things, a car, truck, boat, jet airplane, etc. Since "car" is  a noun, it's called the predicate nominative.]

Here, in this link, look at pages 15, 16, and 17 to learn about action verbs and linking verbs, and the difference between them.

http://images.pcmac.org/SiSFiles/Schools/AL/HooverCity/SpainParkHigh/Uploads/Forms/Start%20Holt%20Handbook%2010.pdf